# Excel, how to put a named range list into one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I put my named range of a list of values into one cell?

i've tried going into a cell and naming the range like so `=namedrange`

sample data in my named range:

```
+---+----------+
|   |    A     |
+---+----------+
| 1 | 'stack', |
| 2 | 'over',  |
| 3 | 'flow',  |
+---+----------+
```

`=OFFSET(Nodes!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(Nodes!$B:$B),1)`

expected output, i would like a formula to do this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, do you have a `textjoin` function?

Comment: Go on Stack overflow and look at the answers for the TEXTJOIN tag.  It is in there multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do 2 cases.  Say the `Named Range` is **A1** through **A3**.  Without `Named Ranges` we can  use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,A1:A3)
```

[image]

With `Named Ranges`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,Stooges)
```

gives the same result.

To use the comma as a separator, replace the ***10*** with ***44***

Comment: what is `textjoin` i dont seem to have that formula. I guess i dont have that excel version.

Comment: may be worth noting TEXTJOIN is not available in 2013 or earlier.  not sure when it was brought in.  I think @ScottCraner has VBA code to produce TEXTJOIN results.